# Celery marks all output as warning

Tags: python, celery

Why does Celery marks all output as warning?
For example:

```
[2012-09-30 16:41:10,718: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@dev-maven has started.
[2012-09-30 16:41:49,219: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: project_reindex.reindex_updated_projects[df28cd38-7582-445b-921b-228ee7570d9f]
[2012-09-30 16:41:52,761: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] Project 51144 indexed.
```

How can I configure it?

Update:

> OS - Ubuntu 10.04
>
> Celery 3.0.7 (Chiastic Slide)
>
> Message broker - RabbitMQ

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more information? What OS are you running, which version of celery etc. :)

Answer (score 16):

Output from `stdout` and `stderr` is redirected to the logger, and the default log level is warning.  You can configure the level or disable the redirection altogether using the
`worker_redirects_stdouts_level` and `worker_redirects_stdouts`  settings:

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#worker-redirect-stdouts

These settings were `CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS_LEVEL` & `CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS` in earlier versions.

Comment: Related Django settings: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings